# Como retornar array de dados com join no Laravel com a classe DB?

Tags: mysql, laravel, query, laravel-5, collection

Preciso de uma ajuda com essa `SQL` do `Laravel`:

```
$process = $db->table('processo')->where('nrprocesso',$id)
 ->leftJoin('viatransporte', function($viatransporte){
      $viatransporte->on('processo.idviatransporte', '=', 'viatransporte.idviatransporte')
      ->whereNotNull('processo.idviatransporte'); })
 ->leftJoin('area', function($area){
     $area->on('processo.idarea', '=', 'area.idarea')
      ->whereNotNull('processo.idarea'); })
 ->leftJoin('moeda', function($moeda){
     $moeda->on('processo.idmoedamle', '=', 'moeda.idmoeda')
       ->whereNotNull('processo.idmoedamle'); });
```

Esse join precisa retorna dois registro que estão no banco, mas retorna apenas um registro, o primeiro, os demais não. Como faço para retornar uma array com todos os registros?

```
->leftJoin('processodocinstrucaodespacho', function($processodocinstrucaodespacho){
  $processodocinstrucaodespacho->on('processo.idprocesso',
                  '=', 'processodocinstrucaodespacho.idprocesso')
     ->where('processodocinstrucaodespacho.iddocinstrucaodespacho', '=', 1); })

->select('processo.*', 'area.aparea', 
         'viatransporte.nmviatransporte', 'moeda.sigla',
         'processodocinstrucaodespacho.nrdocinstrucaodespacho')
->get();
```

Comment: Não seria melhor pegar esse dados através dos relacionamentos entres as entidades? Ficaria algo bem mais claro. Já tentou por esse lado?

Comment: Então, esse banco é remoto estou usando $db = DB::connection('pgsql');, não criei model para essas entidades. estou trabalhando com 2 bancos, o local mysql para guardar algumas informações, e pegando outras desse remoto.

Comment: Qual é a SQL que deve ser correspondente, acho que posso te ajudar a partir dela, uma coisa também o desenho das 3 tabelas e suas chaves são muito importante também para solução.

Comment: O join processodocinstruçáodespacho, no banco quando faço essa mesma consulta retorna mais de 1 registro, mais aqui no código retorna apenas o primeiro que está lá. Muito obrigado

Comment: Por nada @tenorio

Comment: Não resolve o problema, o erro continua